# Alter all tables in schema to set an existing field as an IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY

Tags: postgresql, primary-key, alter-table, identity

Is there an easy and robust way to execute these two commands on all tables in a given schema `myschema` in a PostgreSQL (13) database:

```sql
ALTER TABLE myschema.table001 ADD PRIMARY KEY (oid);
ALTER TABLE myschema.table001 ALTER "oid" ADD GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY;
```

I'm 100% certain that the `oid` field is present in theses tables.

Answer (score 1):

I think this can do the job:

```sql
SELECT format(
  'ALTER TABLE %I.%I ADD PRIMARY KEY (objectid); ALTER TABLE %I.%I ALTER objectid ADD GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY;',
  table_schema, table_name, table_schema, table_name
)
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = 'myschema'
  AND table_type = 'BASE TABLE' \gexec
```

Or better, as suggested by Laurenz:

```sql
SELECT format(
  'ALTER TABLE %I.%I ADD PRIMARY KEY (objectid), ALTER objectid ADD GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY;',
  table_schema, table_name
)
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = 'myschema'
  AND table_type = 'BASE TABLE' \gexec
```